# Having problems with css when creating an indicator notch in my nav

Tags: css, nav

I've been staging up a site and building the basic layout when I ran into a little problem. I want to create a "notched" navigation, but I don't know the first thing about doing this.

I've tried to create a  to be positioned below my  (with the idea that I could either create [with CSS or using an image] a white triangle) that could be aligned with the bottom of my  creating the "notched" effect. I've yet to be successful with this and was hoping someone with css // html wizard status skills could be of assistance.

ps. If you need more info just let me know - I'm a bit new to stackoverflow

Comment: I think you should post your `HTML` and `CSS` code sample here or just setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: You should read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq *If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.*

Comment: Many ways around this. You could add a class of "current" or "active" to the ul li in the navigation and than target with a ul#navigation li.current or active {background-image: url("white triangle.gif";}. That's just one way. As @SheikhHeera (love his name) says, very hard to say without your HTML/CSS.

Comment: @Jawad, +1 for this love, by the way it's shortened, long version is `Sheikh Muhammed Ansar Uddin Heera`  :-)

Comment: @SheikhHeera: Yeah I know. You told be that once before. Can't dig out the post though.

Comment: @Jawad, Yes man, I can remember you now.

Comment: Gotcha. I've setup a jsfiddle with the header html // css here http://jsfiddle.net/nPJxv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cappuccino is using the following css to mark the link tag.

```
<style>
        #navmarker {
        width: 1px;
        height: 0;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -0.7em;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-bottom: #FFD48E solid 0.8em;
        border-top: none;
        border-left: transparent solid 0.8em;
        border-right: transparent solid 0.8em;
        }

        div {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
```

Try to create a div and use the above css it worked for me.

```
    <div id="navmarker"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helping a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Make your NAV LI tags & the A tags within them stretch all the way down to the top of your content block.

When an LI is the 'current' tag then place a triangle graphic as the background of the A tag within it.

```
li.current a {
    background:url(triangle.png) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

You'll probably want the triangle to be blue the same as the blue bar at the top of the content block.